# Javascript function Number.parseLocale returns NaN when there is negative number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following JS method which variable percentageValue returns correct if the number is positive number but if the number is negative it returns NaN. I don't know how to solve it.

```
    function Test() {
    debugger;
    var catLength= $("[id$=lblCat]").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < catLength- 1; i++) {
        var categoryValue = Number.parseLocale($("[id$=" + i + "_lblCat]")[0].title);
        var percentageValue = Number.parseLocale(($("[id$=" + i + "_txtPercentage]")[0].value).replace("%", ""));

    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the html

Comment: `Number.parseLocale` is `undefined` in Chrome.

Comment: you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` for it

Comment: JavaScript's `Number` **has** no `parseLocale` function. [See the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/). There's no [harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?do=index&id=harmony%3Aharmony) or even a [strawman](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?do=index&id=strawman%3Astrawman) proposal for it, so it's not in the works. You'll have to refer to whatever library you're using that's adding it.

Comment: Number.parseLocale(n) is added by microsoftAjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to do

```
var num  = $("[id$=" + i + "_txtPercentage]")[0].value).replace("%", "");
//lets say num is 3500
num.toLocaleString();//returns for me 3 500
```

Documentation: [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard `parseInt` :

```
var a = parseInt("-2");
var b = parseInt("2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AV4rB/

Standard number object does not have `parseLocale` method:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number)
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "MAX_VALUE", "MIN_VALUE", "NaN", "NEGATIVE_INFINITY", "POSITIVE_INFINITY", "isFinite", "isNaN"]
```

Comment: `parseInt` is unlikely to do whatever `parseLocale` does, based on the name. Specifically, `parseInt("1,200", 10)` is `1`, whereas in my locale (UK English) it's actually 1200. In some other locales, `1.200` is 1200, whereas in my locale it's 1 and 2/10ths. Hence the need for a locale-specific parsing function.

Answer (score 1):

As you will have gathered, JavaScript's `Number` **has** no `parseLocale` function. You'll need to go back to whatever library you're using that's adding it.

If you need to create your own, you may be able to do it like this:

```
(function() {
    var thousandsep, decimalsep, rexFindThousands, rexFindDecimal;

    thousandsep = (1200).toLocaleString().replace(/\d/g, '').substring(0, 1);
    decimalsep = (1.2).toLocaleString().repalce(/\d/g, '').substring(0, 1);
    if (!thousandsep) {
        // Big assumption here
        thousandsep = decimalsep === "." ? "," : ".";
    }
    rexFindThousands = new RegExp("\\" + thousandsep, "g");
    rexFindDecimals = new RegExp("\\" + decimalsep, "g");

    Number.prototype.parseLocaleString = function(str) {
        str = String(str).replace(rexFindThousands, '').replace(rexFindDecimals, '.');
        return parseFloat(str);
    };
})();
```

That *attempts* to detect the locale-specific thousands and decimal separators, and then adds a function to `Number` that removes the thousands separator entirely and replaces the decimal separator with `.` (the one used by `parseFloat`), and then returns the result of parsing that using `parseFloat`.

But I'll stress that the output of `toLocaleString` is implementation-dependent. The decimal thing is likely to work, but I have no idea how reliable it is for `toLocaleString` to return a string containing a thousands separator, hence the fallback assumption above.

Also note that if the string you're parsing has a `%` in it, you'll want to remove that before parsing it. `parseFloat` will stop when it reaches it (returning the number up to that point), but still, it's cleaner.

See:

- [`Number#toLocaleString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.3)
- [`parseFloat`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function Test() {
debugger;
    var catLength= $("[id$=lblCat]").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < catLength- 1; i++) {
        var categoryValue = parseFloat($("[id$=" + i + "_lblCat]")[0].title, 2);
        var percentageValue = parseFloat(($("[id$=" + i + "_txtPercentage]")[0].value, 2).replace("%", ""));

    }
}
```

Comment: `parseFloat` is unlikely to do whatever `parseLocale` does, based on the name. Specifically, `parseFloat("1,200")` is `1`, whereas in my locale (UK English) it's actually 1200. In some other locales, `1.200` is 1200, whereas in my locale it's 1 and 2/10ths (which is what `parseFloat` returns). Hence the need for a locale-specific parsing function.